# How to improve a constructor that takes a compile-time-known condition?

Tags: c++, constructor, coding-style, c++14

I have a constructor that looks like this:

```
SomeType(const bool condition = true) {
  if (condition) {
    // do some init
  } else {
    // do some other init
  }
}
```

But as `condition` is known at compile time I suspect that this could be improved avoiding to pass a variable and evaluate the if statement at run time. Is this true? How could it be done?

Comment: Look up [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) and [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) in general. Not much can be done to help you without expanding on what the condition is.

Comment: Optimizer may already do the job. `constexpr` may also help.

Comment: Is this micro-optimization really required? Does it work already? Is it at all conceivable that it may not be a compile-time constant in the future? If you answered yes to any of these questions, just keep it as it is. As for your actual question, is it a constant for all instances of the class or each instance may have a different value, which is known at compile-time?

Comment: @NeilKirk I think this is more coding style than micro-optimization. The condition is really simple: sometimes I call `SomeType(true)` and some others `SomeType(false)`.

Comment: Usually such cases are completely inlined by optimizer, see for instance [asm generated by gcc](http://goo.gl/QjP9UA). For small classes I would not bother at all. Anyway you can measure bottlenecks and look through asm if needed.

Comment: @Jarod42 How would you use `constexpr`?

Comment: Would you be able to use a SFINAE technique of some sort?

Comment: @DarioP: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d564a9d361a2e91)

Comment: In this case, using a normal parameter allows the value to be determined at run-time. By switching to a template parameter, you are taking away some flexibility. There is no point doing that without some gain. The gain from using a template is, `possibly` some performance improvement. In this case, it's unlikely there will be a performance improvement. This isn't coding style but a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 3):

There is no syntax in C++ to call a simple templated constructor like

```
struct SomeType
{
    template <bool condition>
    SomeType();
};

template<>
SomeType::SomeType<true>()
{
    // do some init
}

template<>
SomeType::SomeType<false>()
{
    // do some other init
}

// ...

SomeType<true> st; // this syntax is used to create an object of a class template:

// template <bool>
// struct SomeType
// {
// };
```

One well-known workaround is to imitate template specialization via function overloading:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct SomeType
{
    SomeType(std::true_type)
    {
        // do some init
    }

    SomeType(std::false_type)
    {
        // do some other init
    }

    template <bool condition>
    static SomeType New()
    {
        return SomeType(std::integral_constant<bool, condition>{});
    }
};
```

Example of use:

```
auto st = SomeType::New<false>();
```

In this code C++11 `std::integral_constant` template class from `type_traits` header is used but it is simply enough to write a similar class template in C++03.

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a4c6a7bad078ee7)

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is always a compile time constant, you can do
something like:

```
class SomeType
{
    void initTrue() {}
    void initFalse() {}
public:
    template <bool C>
    struct Discrim {}
    SomeType( Discrim<true> ) { initTrue(); }
    SomeType( Discrim<false> ) { initFalse(); }
};
```

You would then have to invoke it with:

```
SomeType((SomeType::Discrim<condition>()));
```

Or you could simply define two enums, on which you could
overload the constructor:

```
class SomeType
{
    void initTrue() {}
    void initFalse() {}
public:
    enum ConditionTrue { conditionTrue };
    enum ConditionFalse { conditionFalse };
    SomeType( ConditionTrue ) { initTrue(); }
    SomeType( ConditionFalse ) { initFalse(); }
};
```

Or you can just do what you're doing; it's highly unlikely that
the extra test will add a measurable difference to the run time.
And if it does (as shown by the profiler), it can only be that
the constructor is small enough to be inlined (in which case,
constant propagation in the optimizer will ensure that there is
no actual `if`).  The above techniques are typically only useful
when you want separate constructors which have distinctly
different initialization lists.

Comment: 1. You forgot `;` after `struct Discrim` definition. 2. You can't invoke it using code like `SomeType st(SomeType::Discrim<condition>());` due to [the most vexing parse rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) ([proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6c0ba9b2c95abcf)).

Comment: @Constructor Good point.  I've edited to add the extra set of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust to compiler then you (maybe) can do your class's constructor as a template:

```
template< bool condition >
SomeType();

template<>
SomeType< true >() {
    // do some init
}
template<>
SomeType< false >() {
    // do some other init
}
```

**Edit:**
As @Constructor (the name says it all))) said you can't call this type of constructor. Therefore you can move all initialization in function. Like this:

```
struct SomeType {
    template< bool condition >
    void init();
};
template<>
void SomeType::init< true >() {
  // do some init
}
template<>
void SomeType::init< false >() {
  // do some other init
}

SomeType t;
t.init< true >();
SomeType f;
f.init< false >();
```

http://ideone.com/3CJS41

Comment: No, you can't. There is no syntax in C++ to call such templated constructor.